# function never end cuz of while()

Tags: c

the adder supports integer addition up to 30 digits
operator only '+'
no array, pointer

when digits is over 30, print "overflow"

i tried to get number getchar() function.
I received a 30-digit integer divided by 15 digits. cuz there is rule do not use real type data.

when i put 1000+1000
there is no answer. i think while () never ends
i dont know why it is ???

this is my code... i am not good at coding.
I just learned coding, so the code is cluttered.
Also, It may sound awkward because i am not good at speaking eng. ^^

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    
    int start = 1, calcu = 1;
    char ent, anw, trash;

    while (start) {

        int c1 = 1, opd = 0, check = 1, finish = 0;
        int cnt1 = 0, cnt2 = 0, over = 0;
        long long int t1 = 0, t2 = 0, sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
        long long int sum3 = 0, sum4 = 0;

        printf("Input : ");

        while (calcu) {

            while (c1 == 1) {

                ent = getchar();

                if ('0' <= ent && ent <= '9') {

                    if (cnt1 < 15) {
                        sum1 = sum1 * 10 + (ent - '0');
                        ++cnt1;
                    }
                    else if (15 <= ent && ent < 30) {
                        sum2 = sum2 * 10 + (ent - '0');
                        ++cnt1;
                    }
                    else c1 = 0;
                }

                else if (ent == ' ')
                    continue;

                else if (ent == '+') {
                    c1 = 0;
                }
                else
                    opd = 1;
            }

            while (c1 == 0) {

                ent = getchar();

                if ('0' <= ent && ent <= '9') {

                    if (cnt2 < 15) {
                        sum3 = sum3 * 10 + (ent - '0');
                        ++cnt2;
                    }
                    else if (15 <= cnt2 && cnt2 < 30) {
                        sum4 = sum4 * 10 + (ent - '0');
                        ++cnt2;
                    }
                    else
                        c1 = -1;
                }
                else if (cnt2 == ' ') {
                    ++cnt2;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                    c1 = -1;
            }

        }

        printf("Output : ");

        if (opd == 1) {
            printf("wrong operator");
        }
        else {
            t1 = sum1 + sum3;
            t2 = sum2 + sum4;

            if (t2 >= 1000000000000000) {
                t1 += 1;
            }
            if (t1 >= 1000000000000000) {
                over = 1;
            }
        }
        if (over == 1) {
            printf("overflow\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("%lld%015lld", t1, t2);
        }

        while (check) {
            printf("continue ?");
            scanf("%c", &anw);
            trash = getchar();

            if (anw == 'y' || anw == 'Y')
                check = 0;
            else if (anw == 'n' || anw == 'N') {
                check = 0;
                finish = 1;
            }
            else continue;
        }

        if (finish == 1)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: About code blocks on SO: Note that code gets appropriately formatted if you either indent consistently by four spaces or put a pair of tripple back-ticks (`\`\`\``) around, as I did for you.

Comment: You do not end the nested loop (testing `calcu`), you neither set `calcu` to false/0 once you're done nor `break` the loop.

Comment: Side note: You don't ever modify `start` either, instead you just `break` the loop; in such case you should rather drop the `start` variable entirely and either write `while(1)` or (which I prefer) `for(;;)`.

Comment: I personally would drop the `check` and `finished` variables as well: `for(;;) { /* calculate */ for(;;) { if(anw == 'y' || anw == 'Y') { break; /* just the nested loop */ } if(anw == 'n' || anw == 'N') { goto DONE; /* leave both loops */ } /* just continue iterating */ } /* just continue as well, user entered 'y' */ } DONE: return 0;`

Comment: Side note 2: `trash = getchar();` – I assume you want to consume the terminating newline character, don't you? But what, if a user enters `yes` instead??? You could consume all characters by `do { trash = ...; } while(trash != '\n' && trash != EOF);`; note that `trash` needs to be `int` for (which is what `getchar` actually returns) to be able to catch EOF at all.

Comment: Thanks to u, the result is not correct, but it ends normally... Thank u for your kind reply.. It's chilly at night here. Always stay healthy... :D

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your program never ends, is because that when the program reaches your while loops with `start` and `calcu` as the variables that determine when your loop is supposed to keep running or stop (conditional statement, the condition in parenthesis after while), the program will keep checking what the value of `start` and `calcu` for every time the loop is to be repeated.

`1` and `true` are equal in C, meaning you can use either one to represent a true statement. Because `start` and `calcu` are always 1, and never changed inside the while loops themselves, this means the program will always read them as `true`. Therefore, it will keep running the while-loop until the variables are `false`, but this never happens inside the while loops.

To solve the issue, you have to decide where in the respective while loop you want the addition to stop and change the `start` and `calcu` variable to 0 respectively, the reason being that `0` and `false` can represent a false statement.

Comment: Oh, i was missing that part perfectly,,,,, Thank you for your quick reply.... i dont know where you live, but it's chilly as the seasons change rapidly... Take care.. :D

Comment: @chicken True for the `calcu` loop, however there's a `break` aborting the `start` loop... Admitted, instead of setting `finished` I'd rather have set `start` to 0 on reading `n` – but that's another matter.